# Nodejs Oracle db: What is error code NJS 105

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I am running a node service that inserts somedata into an oracle Table. However i am getting
:{"code":"NJS-105"} in some cases. I tried googling the code to see what it meant but couldn't find it

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.